# Excel: How do I perform bitwise counting?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with close to 13 columns with 0's and 1's. I want to perform bitwise counting on columns like so:

```
A   B   Result
1   1   1
0   1   1
1   0   1
0   0   0
```

I tried lookup, vlookup, countif(s), but nothing seems to be working for me? Are there any other functions I could use?

*** EDIT ***

I am actually looking to implement this in Python because it is part of a rather long workflow and I don't want to interrupt the script by having to exit do this and then come back. What is a a rather naive way of doing this in Python?

So far, I have tried to write something where I ask the user to provide an input of which columns they would like grouped but I could not make it work.

Thanks,

Comment: what are the requirements - i.e. result column should be 1 if there is 1 or more 1's in the previous columns?

Comment: `=--OR(A1,B1)` maybe in Column C?

Comment: I've never seen the double unary operator before. That's neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a bitwise OR (as your example seems to show) you can just put this formula in your Result column

`=MIN(SUM(A1:B1),1)`

And then just copy down

Or, you could use the OR function, which will return True if any value is 1 and False if all 0

`=IF(OR(A1:B1),1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will output 1 or 0, depending if there are 1 or more 1's in the columns A->C...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"=1")>1,1,0)
```